# NetSuite: canceling an order in SuiteScript

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

In NetSuite, there is a handy button to cancel a `salesorder`.  We are trying to replicate the behavior of that click in a RESTlet.  We tried the following:

```
var order = nlapiLoadRecord('salesorder', 802);
order.setFieldText('orderstatus', 'Cancelled');
nlapiSubmitRecord(order);
```

But we got an error saying that we needed to enter a value for the field `Status`.  We also tried the following:

```
nlapiVoidTransaction('salesorder', 802);
```

But this gave us an invalid record type error.  Any thoughts or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an open enhancement request for this (#275848).  According to NetSuite support, there is no way to cancel a sales order via SuiteScript or Workflow.

Comment: In which tracker is this request id? Is there any update on this ?

Comment: SuiteIdeas.  In NetSuite, navigate to `Support > Support Overview`.  Click on the "Go To SuiteIdeas button.  Enter the ID above to find that specific enhancement request.  It currently has 55 votes....whatever that means.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
nlapiRequestURL('/app/accounting/transactions/salesordermanager.nl?type=cancel&id=' + nlapiGetRecordId());
```

Comment: Good but not safe, if netsuite changes the cancel URL, the script won't work

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, instead of cancelling the sales order, could you not just set the `closed` field to 'T'.

Answer (score 0):

## Sales Order can be closed by closing each line of item using SuiteScript 2.0 as follows:

```
orderRecord.setCurrentSublistValue({
                            sublistId: 'item',
                            fieldId: 'isclosed',
                            value: true
                        });
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use following code and order status code to set via SuiteScript -

```
nlapiSubmitField('salesorder',soID,'orderstatus','C',false);
```

Comment: As an FYI—this didn’t work.  It gave the same error:

Answer (score -2):

As Netsuite Expert said, you can cancel the sales order transaction by
closing each line items in the sales order.

```
for(var i = 1; i <= nlapiGetLineItemCount('item'); i++){
    nlapiSetLineItemValue('item', 'isclosed', i, 'T');
}
```

This is a sample for User event script.

Comment: It will close the sale order, not cancel it

Comment: Cancelled Sales Order is different from Closed Sales Order